# Should I use mysqli prepare statement everytime I insert, update & delete a record?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepare

My main concern is the security of inserting, updating, & deleting of record in my database table.

If I use the following code:

```
    $sql_room = "UPDATE `lf_rooms` SET room_count`=$room_count
                    WHERE id = $room_id";

    mysqli_query($con, $sql_room);
```

Is this secure or do I need to use prepare statement?

Comment: There's little downside to using a prepared statement, considering the fact that it could save your database.

Comment: Prepare when you input user data, or you can choose to use [`mysqli_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php) instead

Comment: As for security, if `$room_count` and `$room_id` are user inputs, then it's particularly *insecure*.

Comment: @arxanas what is the downside?

Comment: @Matchu it's a user input taken from $_POST.

Comment: @jaypabs As far as I understand, it's negligible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363039/are-there-downsides-to-using-prepared-statements

Comment: @AlvinWong should I use mysqli_escape_string every time there is data inputted user?