# Secure PHP Query?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a page to activate users who click the activation link in an email I send them, the email contains a url which posts there email address using the GET method, My code is as follows but what im asking is this a secure method or is there any way it can be imporved? Thanks

```
$username = $_GET['email']; 

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET active = 'yes'
WHERE email = '$username'") or die('oops!');

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/index.php?msg=active\">";
```

Comment: Just call me [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). Or use [PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379433/mysql-prepared-statements).

Comment: Also check out prepared statements: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html

Comment: potential for ultimate destruction there.  at least use mysql_real_escape_string.  I was about to type that as an answer, but a billion people already said the same thing.  always validate your input before sending it to the database.

Comment: I don't have enough downvotes to downvote all the answers that didn't mention PDO or prepared statements, or to upvote all the ones that did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following value of $_GET['email']:

```
"'; DELETE FROM users WHERE 1 or username = ''"
```

If your user submits this value, your script will execute the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE users SET active = 'yes' WHERE email = ''; DELETE FROM users WHERE 1 or username = ''"
```

You will need to filter your input to remove characters that have meaning in an SQL setting (\' in this example).

You can help secure your queries by using PDO prepared statements, or by filtering using mysql_real_escape_string().

Additionally, you want to create a unique, non-guessable value to send to the user, and expect that value back from $_GET. If you allow the user to supply a plain-text email address, a malicious user can activate *any* email address. md5() or other hash functions can be used to create unique values.

Comment: Although the some ideas of this post are correct, mysql cannot actually execute more than one statement in a single call to `mysql_query()`. SQL injection is still a vulnerability, but an attacker won't actually be able to delete all users from an update statement.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the best method for activating an email. Anyone could register with a fake email and create their own GET request to activate it. You should use a unique hash instead that cannot be guessed. Also, you need to escape your SQL statement with mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 5):

Forget about `mysql_real_escape_string` — see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690795/am-i-safe-using-just-mysql-real-escape-string-to-defend-sql-injections/5690877#5690877 and [Do htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string keep my PHP code safe from injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-injec).

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

- [MySQL Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379433/mysql-prepared-statements)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Don't forget about [second-order SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/134138#134138) (what, no one told you that security is hard?). More info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlInjectionAttacks.aspx#pre13).

Comment: Thank, may I ask why I should forget mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: @Liam see my edit. Basically, you have to **always** remember to escape **everything.**

Comment: Thanks a lot @matt, appreciate it!

Comment: This is the only correct answer so far other than @Michael's.

Comment: @Lotus more than one Michael has posted an answer

Answer (score 3):

This is not at all secure.  You need to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on your `$username`

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
```

Better would be to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and pass the variable in through a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 2):

No, that's vulnerable to SQL injection. I can place a `'` in `$_GET['email']` and run any query I like.

Answer (score 2):

This is most definitely not secure. You need to escape any potentially dangerous characters (think if someone entered a ' in their email address) via `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not secure. You should either use stored procedures, or [escape the sql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 2):

Imagine for a moment, that I want to do something malicious to you site, now suppose that I manipulate your URL and change `.php?email=arron@arronchapman.com` to `.php?email=1';SHOW TABLES` or maybe even `.php?email=1';DROP TABLE USERS;` that wouldn't be very nice would it?

The simplest way to prevent this is to wrap all of your input values in the function [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), this would make your query look like this:
`mysql_query("UPDATE users SET active = 'yes' WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) .'") or die('oops!');`

I'd like to introduce you to my friend Bobby Tables (From [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/327/)):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the SQL injection issues that everyone else mentioned, you have the problem of people being able to forge their own activation link and bypass the need for receiving the email.

A common solution is to include some sort of hash value in the URL that you check before activating.

For example -

Create a table for activations. When the user signs up, insert the email address (or some other unique identifier) and some non-constant, secret value.  This could be a random number, a timestamp and a salt, or similar.

When you generate the link for the email, include a hash value obtained from hashing both the email address and the secret value.

Then when the user clicks on the link, you can take the email address from the URL, hash it with the value in the database, and see if it matches the hash in the URL.

This will make it much harder for someone to forge an activation link.

Answer (score 0):

While, as everyone is saying, it is an absolute necessity to escape your string before using it in a query, I think there is more be concerned with.

This still allows non users to try different email addresses and see what the result will be.

I recommend encrypting the email, and using the encrypted version of the email in the url.

So when you send them the link:

```
$enc_key = 'SOME KEY I USE';
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$result = $db->query("SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('$email', '$enc_key') as email");
$enc_email = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$enc_email = $enc_email['email'];
$url = "http://www.example.com/confirm.html?key=$enc_email";
```

then to check for the user on confirm you:

```
$enc_key = 'SOME KEY I USE';
$enc_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key']);
$result = $db->query("UPDATE users SET active = 1 WHERE AES_ENCRYPT(email, '$enc_key') = '$enc_email'");
```