# Which one is faster and lighter - mysqli & PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I am using **MySQL** with **PHP5**. I got to know that ancient `mysql_*` functions are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). So I decided to move away from `mysql_*`. The question is where to? I am looking for lighter, simpler and faster way. Somebody tell me which among these (`mysqli` and `PDO`) is;

1. faster
2. easy to learn and code
3. consumes less space and memory

*Note: Tutorial links in beginner level for these two will be helpful.*

Comment: It's not exactly the answer you're looking for but a lot of good info is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons

Comment: Nobody has really commented on point #3...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**[PDO vs. MySQLi: Which Should You Use?](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)**

> Both **PDO** and **MySQLi** offer an **object-oriented API**, but MySQLi also
>   offers a **procedural API** – which makes it easier for newcomers to
>   understand. If you are familiar with the native PHP MySQL driver, you
>   will find migration to the procedural MySQLi interface much easier. On
>   the other hand, once you master PDO, you can use it with any database
>   you desire!

[image: Summary]

[image: DataBase Support]

> **Ultimately, PDO wins** this battle with ease. With support for twelve
>   different database drivers (eighteen different databases!) and named
>   parameters, we can ignore the small performance loss, and get used to
>   its API. From a security standpoint, both of them are **safe** as long as
>   the developer uses them the way they are supposed to be used.

***So if you’re still working with MySQLi, maybe it’s time for a change!***

**[PDO vs. MySQLi: Which Should You Use? - By Dejan Marjanovic](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)**

Hope this helps .

Comment: Both extensions support the [MySQL Native Driver](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.library.choosing.html) which is a hell of a beast and if you're using Mysql + PHP you need to understand that this is a luxury position in web-development.

Comment: So you copied over large parts of an article written by someone else and gave that as "your" answer? You should praise the guy who has wrote that piece I suggest before doing so.

Comment: @hakre I've mentioned him dude. and if some one have written it in a better way then why need to write a whole new answer. Got my point?!

Comment: @AlphaMale: I don't see Webarto's name here. Learn how to properly quote and how to give credit.

Comment: What do you mean mysqli doesn't support prepared statements? The documentation says otherwise: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @ashgromnies It says clearly "CLIENT-SIDE PREPARED STATEMENTS", MYSQLi extension does not supports clientside prepared statements but using Using PDO MySQL Driver and MySQL Native Driver you can d that easily. The Same Documentation says this too: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php#usernotes

Comment: @ashgromnies and here it is also mentioned clearly "The API does not include emulation for client-side prepared statement emulation." have a look: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php For further clearance on what client-side statements are Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146733/what-are-client-side-prepared-statements

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above question, here is a comparison chart;

[image]

And the information at **[Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)** is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**About Performance**

While both PDO and MySQLi are quite fast, MySQLi performs insignificantly faster in benchmarks - ~2.5% for non-prepared statements, and ~6.5% for prepared ones. The MySQL extension was even faster.