# MySQLi Prepared Statements - Passing an Array

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having some real difficulties with my code here. I'm trying to pass an array of data to a function and have it dynamically build a INSERT statement using prepared statements.

So I have this:

```
    public function create($data) {
        global $mysqli;
        foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
            $fields[] = $field;
            $values[] = $value;
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->class_name . " (";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
            if ($i == (count($fields) - 1)) {
                $query .= "" . $fields[$i] . "";
            } else {
                $query .= "" . $fields[$i] . ", ";
            }
        }
        $query .= ") VALUES (";
        $params = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
            if (is_int($values[$i])) {
                $params[] = "i";
            } else {
                $params[]= "s";
            }
            if ($i == (count($values) - 1)) {
                $query .= "?";
            } else {
                $query .= "?, ";
            }
        }
        $query .= ")";
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge($params, $values));
        } else {
            die("COULD NOT CONNECT create()");
        }
        //echo $query;
    }
```

The issues is I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in E:\xampp2\htdocs\school2\application\models\CRUDAObject.php on line 44

I'm pretty new to prepared statements, but I can't work out which format/layout the array needs to be when I pass it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120822/mysqli-bind-param-expected-to-be-a-reference-value-given) will probably help you. You need to make an array of references instead of passing your existing `array_merge()` directly...

Comment: If you're not completely married to using MySQLi you could always jump ship to PDO where you can choose to bind by reference, or by value. Just sayin...

Comment: Yep - things like this are far easier to accomplish with PDO.

Comment: Looking at that other post, I'm still not quite sure what you mean. Do I need to construct the array differently? EDIT: Not completely married to MySQLi - but I'm a bit limited about what I can modify about this project

Comment: you first loop to generate the field names could be simplified down to just `implode(',', $fields)`, basically.

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.6 this has become ridiculously simple, without the need for call_user_func_array. The trick is to use the splat ("unpack") operator (**...**) for your value list. Scroll down for ***"The Short Version"*** or feel free to read through to see how I'm handling the various data elements involved in the SQL transaction.

I do three things, using three functions I wrote.

1. I create a key=>value array where the key is an exact match for the MySQL column name.
2. I create a string containing the data types (eg: 'ssssdssbn').
3. I have a function that creates my dynamic references for the insert statement

After that, it's pretty simple.

So, first, the ground work:

```
// This would be passed to a functionized version of this:
    // $MySQLInsertArray is an array of key=>value where key is db column name
    // $MySQLDataTypes is a list of data types used to bind, eg: 'sssdsdnb'

// This creates the reference pointers for the insert statement (eg: '?,?,?,?')
    $MySQLQs=str_repeat("?,",strlen($MySQLDataTypes)-1)."?";



// Make a *STRING* of the column names
    $ColumnList=implode(",",array_keys($MySQLInsertArray));

// Make an *ARRAY WITH NO KEYS* of the values
    $ValueList=array_values($MySQLInsertArray);

// Do all the fun SQL stuff
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$TBName." (".$ColumnList.") VALUES (".$MySQLQs.")");

// USE THE UNPACK OPERATOR (...)
    $stmt->bind_param($MySQLDataTypes,...$ValueList);
    $stmt->execute();
```

**The short version is:**

- Build a string of the names of the columns (comma separated).
- Build an array of the values (no key names) - it is "$ValueList" in the statement below.
- Use the unpack operator in your bind_param statement to unpack the values in $ValueList. It's literally that easy now.

So, that means, the important part is this and those magic three periods:

> $stmt->bind_param($MySQLDataTypes,***...***$ValueList);

Comment: Just to let you know, splat operator is 5.6 and there is implode() in PHP.