# php dynamic mysql query for filters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, dynamic-programming

I am trying to implement dynamic sql query so that users has flexibility to use one or more filters to dig out the data he wants. I am using prepared statements to ensure that there is no SQL Injection. I am using WAMP Server 64 bit.
I referred to this article for writing my code: [Sample](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli)

Following is my code:

```
$myqry="SELECT * FROM students WHERE ";
$initflag=0; //controls the first clause without AND and rest with AND
$paramtypes=array();
$paramvalues=array();
$params=array();
if(!empty($_POST['awr_admyear']))
{
    $myqry.= "YEAR(adm_date)=? ";
    $initflag=1;
    $paramtypes[]='s';
    $paramvalues[]=$_POST['awr_admyear'];
}
if(!empty($_POST['awr_admfrom']) && !empty($_POST['awr_admto']))
{
    if($initflag==0)
        $myqry.= "YEAR(adm_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
    else
        $myqry.= "AND YEAR(adm_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
    $initflag=1;
    $paramtype[]='s';
    $paramtype[]='s';
    $paramvalues[]=$_POST['awr_admfrom'];
    $paramvalues[]=$_POST['awr_admto'];
}
if(!empty($_POST['awradm_no']))
{
    if($initflag==0)
        $myqry.= "adm_no LIKE ? ";
    else
        $myqry.= "AND adm_no LIKE ? ";
    $initflag=1;
    $paramtype[]='s';
    $paramvalues[]=$_POST['awradm_no'];
}
$params = array_merge($paramtype,$paramvalues);
if(isset($myqry) && !(empty($myqry)))
{
    if($result1 = $mysqli->prepare($myqry))
    {
        call_user_func_array(array($result1, 'bind_param'), $params);
        if($result1->execute())
        {
            $finrest=$result1->get_result();
            while($row= $finrest->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
  //and so on
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in..................
```

Where I am going wrong and what is the solution?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120822/mysqli-bind-param-expected-to-be-a-reference-value-given)

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: @hungrykoala That did the trick. But in code above, second if section passes two parameters instead of only one and this brings the error as: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesnt match number of bind variables

Comment: @YourCommonSense 5.6.25

Comment: check the bind_param() definition and what you are sending there. And for goodnes sake, switch for PDO

Comment: @YourCommonSense this is my bind_param definition: call_user_func_array(array($result1, 'bind_param'), $params);     and can see in the code above, all parameters are passed fine, still do a cross check for me

Comment: @YourCommonSense Also, echo count($paramtype); count($paramvalues);count($params); returns 3, 3, and 6 respectively when i use second and third if blocks. Count is correct for me according to the if blocks code. I also looped through and printed the values of all arrays, value sets are correct.

Comment: The query i got by using 2nd and 3rd if blocks is: 
SELECT * FROM students WHERE (YEAR(adm_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND adm_no LIKE ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I found that whenever there are more than 1 clauses in the generated SQL query, i get the same error about number of parameters.

Comment: check the **mysqli_statement::bind_param() function definition** and compare to what you are sending there.

Comment: And for goodnes sake, switch for PDO, where you will need just `$result1->execute($params);` instead of all that mess.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I already mentioned above that everything seems fine and i dont understand why its is not taking equal number of parameters. Please suggest a solution

Comment: Everything is fine? All right, what are correct parameters for bind_param()?

Comment: @YourCommonSense My query is: SELECT * FROM students WHERE YEAR(adm_date)=? AND adm_no LIKE ?

Parameter values in paramtype array are:   ss and

Parameter values in paramvalues array are:  1978%2%    ---  Then I pass these values as: call_user_func_array(array($result1, 'bind_param'), refValues($params));

Comment: what is "ss"? where did you get it? I don't see any code above that can give you a string like this

Comment: @YourCommonSense  In every if block, i have appended s to create a list of parameter types.   In the code above, it is written as:  $paramtype[]='s';  In current scenario, I am working on first and third if blocks passing 1978 and 2 as the values i textboxes.

Comment: Don't tell me what is written in your code. I can read it all right. Tell me where did you get that "ss". show me the code that can print it

Comment: This I have used at my end recently to test after you startedasking about the parameter checking.       for($i=0; $i<count($paramtype);$i++)  { echo $paramtype[$i]; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Follow this answer, mentioned here: [mysqli bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120822/mysqli-bind-param-expected-to-be-a-reference-value-given)

2) Do the following changes:

`$params = array_merge($paramtype,$paramvalues);`

Replace it with:

```
$params[] = implode("", $paramtype);
```

`$params = array_merge($params, $paramvalues);`

$paramtype is array but bind_param needs first parameter should be string.