# PDO/OOP Search Engine php

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I can't seem to place what is wrong in the code :

This is where the function takes place and execute. this is from a different file

```
public function search($title, $table)
    {

        $q = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE (':title' LIKE '%".$title."%')";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
        $stmt->execute(array(':title' => $title));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
```

This part should check and results. different file again

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $search = $_POST['search'];   
     $min_length = 2;

    if(strlen($search) >= $min_length){

        $search = htmlspecialchars($search); 
        $results = $code->search($title, "book_info"); //the error is here*

        if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0){ // the error is here too**

            while($results != $code->fetchAll()){
            echo "<table id=\"tablecolor\" class=\"echoname\" >";
            echo "<th><b>ID</b></th>";
            echo "<th><b>Title</b></th>";
            echo "<th><b>Author</b></th>";
            echo "<th><b>ISBN</b></th>";
            echo "<th><b>Publisher</b></th>";
            echo "<th><b>Language</b></th>";
            echo "<th><b>Genre</b></th>";
            echo "<th><b>Quantity</b></th>";
            echo "<pre>";  
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$title."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$author."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$isbn."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$publisher."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$language."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$genre."</td>";
                    echo "<td><center>".$quantity."</center></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";    
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "</table>";

            }

        }
        else{ 
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
}
```

This is the error when executed

```
*Notice: Undefined variable: title in C:\wamp\www\unitato\web\user\user-search1.php on line 16
**Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in C:\wamp\www\unitato\web\user\user-search1.php on line 18
```

I want to know how to fix this error.

Comment: Where do you think `$title` is coming from? It does not exist, as the error message is saying. Why are you using mysql_ functions on a PDO result?

Comment: ohh yeah sorry i didnt realize that. and what is wrong with using msql_ functions on a PDO result?

Comment: mysql_ functions only work on values/variables produced by mysql_ functions. PDO is a completely different API.

Comment: okay... Ill study on those stuffs. I still don't know what their relationship is. Thank You for telling me sir

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10703665/476

Comment: ohh that is soo cool .. thank you for this sir. you have given me ideas. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two things wrong:

- **First:** You are trying to use `mysql_fetch_rows()` when you are using PDO. One is for mysql other is for PDO. So, They are two completely different constructs, so don't mix them up.
- **Second**: You are assuming all `SELECT` statement is going to return some value, by simply doing `fetchAll` afterwards.

  *What if the query was not successful ? How can `fetchAll()` get you anything?

If you want to check your `SELECT` statement is returning any value you can do this from the function using `rowCount()` method.

```
public function search($title, $table)
{
        try{
        $q = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE title LIKE ?";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
        $stmt->execute(array("%$title%");
        }catch(PDOException $e){
         throw new Exception("ERROR:". $e->getMessage()); 
        }
        if(!$stmt->rowCount()){
          return false; #this will return false if data isn't found. 
        }
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
}
```

Or instead of `mysql_fetch_rows` outside you function you can check do:

```
$results = $code->search($title, "book_info");
if($result){
 //query is ok
}
```

Comment: Thank You sir. It works but it wont display results.. I guess the problem is  on my database. I can handle it from here.. Thank You very much. :D (y)

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check the script again. It is likely that you are asking mysql to give you a data that does not exist.

Comment: Yeah.. it is fine now.. my database is empty.. i didnt realize. Thank you again sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

a **proper** version

```
public function search($title)
{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute(array("%$title%"));
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Note that table and field name are **hardcoded** in the query as they should be.

Comment: Btw: I think you are wrong in assuming that table/field names should be hard coded. Where did you ever read that from ?

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
public function search($title, $table)
{

    $q = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE title LIKE '%:title%'";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute(array(':title' => $title));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```