# Using external variables in classes

Tags: php

I have a directory structure:

```
app
cofig
 config.php
classes
 db.class.php
index.php
```

config.php:

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_USER', 'root'); 
define('DB_PASS', ''); 
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');
```

db.class.php:

```
<?php 
include "config/config.php";

class DB {

private $conn;
private $results;

public function __construct() {

$this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);//**This doesn't work**
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->conn);
}

}
?>
```

when I try to create an instance of the $db class in index.php, I get errors (cannot obtain DEFINED variables in class)

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: This should work .... are you sure you have `require_once()`'d config.php ?

Comment: are you using the wrong config file or is it just a type o? you have imported db.config but defined vars in config.php

Comment: I've edited the code, it was a typo

Answer (score 3):

Having this directory structure:

```
app
config
 config.php
classes
 db.class.php
index.php
```

will force you to use: `include('../config/config.php');` or define an absolute `PATH` that goes to the root and do: `include(PATH.'config/config.php');`.

Your `include "config/config.php";` is interpreted as `include('root/classes/config/config.php')` which, I assume, doesn't exists.

You should anyway pass, as Samy suggested, constants to the class via constructor so that you can use the same class for multiple connection with different database variables.

And also, it is not suggested to use mysql or mysqli function anymore. Learn about PDO.

Comment: You're right, but including isn't the fix, I still cannot get defined DB_ variables from the db class

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "cofig" in your directory structure is a typo, use:

```
include("../config/config.php");
```

Comment: Ok, even fixing that, it cannot access DB_HOST, DB_PASS etc from the class

Comment: Yes I can, before class definition. But cannot access them from within the db class

Comment: Move the include line within your constructor.

Comment: Did that fix the problem? If so, you can mark this answer correct so that others know the problem is solved.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not the cause; the real cause was putting comment right behind the opening <?php this way:  <?php/* comment */

Answer (score 2):

According to your directory structure include path should be '../config/config.php'.
Since you are using include, it does not throw fatal error and continue code execution whther file is included or not. 
Here your file is not included as per the code. Try this

```
  <?php 
include "../config/config.php";

class DB {

    private $conn;
    private $results;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);//**This doesn't work**
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->conn);
     }

 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass these variables to your class as parameters, it's cleaner anyway.

```
class DB {
    public function __construct($host, $dbName, $user, $password) {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
        mysql_select_db($dbName, $this->conn);
    }
}

new DB(DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

By the way, [*mysql_* functions are in the process of being deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Comment: "By the way, mysql_ functions are deprecated." Useful comment

Comment: What do you recommend instead? PDO.. or..?

Comment: PDO or mysqli, though [PDO is probably better.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696696/which-one-is-faster-and-lighter-mysqli-pdo)

Comment: PHP recommend *mysqli* or PDO (http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). -- I'd say PDO... or an ORM. :)

Comment: Did you mean for this function in the first place?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php it has been deprecated as of 5.3.0. I think that mysql_connect, mysql_query still exist