# PHP MySQL PDO, client side or server side prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to find an authoritative answer on whether the PDO_MySQL library in PHP uses client side or server side prepared statements.

The best document so far is this one:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

This suggests that both server and client side prepared statements are supported but there does not appear to be any documentation suggesting how to switch between the two modes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146733/what-are-client-side-prepared-statements

Comment: [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation)

Comment: With PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES. I "assume" true means it's effectively doing client side prepared statements within the PDO layer. But if not set, it's not clear whether statements are prepared client or server side by the underlying mysql libraries.