# Preventing SQL Injection: How do I make this query injection proof

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

New to php & MySQL. Followed a tutorial on Youtube but after messing around a bit I managed to bypass and access my site using admin'# as the username and a blank password. [See here.](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/web-development/503-basic-tests-for-sql-injection-vulnerabilities.html)

My code (PHP):

```html
<?php
 $username = "***";
 $password = "****";
 $hostname = "mysql1.000webhost.com";
 $database = "***_login";
 
 $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password );
 
 
 $selected = mysql_select_db("a7653250_login", $dbhandle)
   or die("Could not connect to database");
 
 $myusername = $_POST['user'];
 $mypassword = $_POST['pass'];
 
 $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
 $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
 $result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
 
 if($count==1){
  $seconds = 186400 + time();
 setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
  header("location:index.php");}
 else{
  header("location:loginfailed.php");
 }
 
 mysql_close()
?>
```

I've read about using some sort of parameters but I don't know where or how to use them.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you know that stackoverflow has a search function ? ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379433/mysql-prepared-statements

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'm a bit confused. Can I get an example of what I would do with $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'"; ?
Very new to this! All help is really appreciated!

Comment: This resource should give you enough information and examples to achieve result form http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 2):

You should be using PHP PDO library http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or at least MySQLi http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

`mysql_` function family is deprecated and insecure by itself

Here you can read about MySQLi prepared statements and parameter binding http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Is MySQLi included with the MySQL & phpMyAdmin package? I'm using free hosting and can't add or remove anything.

Comment: MySQLi extension is included with PHP 5 and higher, it should be available at 000webhost.com as well.