# String contain special characters in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have data in  mysql table something like this (I'm working on kruti dav 010 font)

```
id   name      description 
1     'abc       '"dbs
2     a'bc       <'dns
3     /bc        sb 'dcv
4     x"ydbv     er?$#nv
5     y>/'b      'Dfr>?
6     p;q'd      'df@'d
```

Now i want to perform some operations like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name,description ) VALUES ('x"ydv',''"dbs')
```

When i run  this query values inside of single quotes  there is an error because of '"dbs

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name,description ) VALUES ("x"ydv","'"dbs")
```

Similarly when i  put values inside of double quotes there is an error because of x"ydv and  '"dbs
Now when i want to perform some operation like

```
<?php
$string='dbx;'pq';
echo $string;
?>
```

There is an error because of single quote inside of string
I know solution of this problem using \  i can escape single quote inside of string.

Last problem

```
<?php
$array=Array ( [0] => dchj/kke [1] => jktukanxkao [2] => dksfj;k [3] => ukjk;.kiqj [4] => t'kiqj [5] => jk;x<+ [6] => "dksjck );
print_r($array);
$fields="'".implode("','", $array)."'";
    echo $fields;
$this->db->select('id')->from('village')->where_in("name", $fields);
$query = $this->db->get();
echo $this->db->last_query();
?>
```

Output

```
Array ( 
[0] => dchj/kke 
[1] => jktukanxkao 
[2] => dksfj;k 
[3] => ukjk;.kiqj 
[4] => t'kiqj 
[5] => jk;x<+ 
[6] => "dksjck )

'dchj/kke','jktukanxkao','dksfj;k','ukjk;.kiqj','t'kiqj','jk;x<+','"dksjck'

SELECT `id` FROM (`village`) WHERE `name` IN('\'dchj/kke\',\'jktukanxkao\',\'dksfj;k\',\'ukjk;.kiqj\',\'t\'kiqj\',\'jk;x<+\',\'"dksjck\'')
```

New when i run this query in  mysql

```
 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0025 sec)
```

i have records in database for given array, but mysql  returns zero rows

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379433/mysql-prepared-statements) , prepared statements in **mysqli_*** or **PDO** will make your life easier..

Comment: I'm currently working on codeigniter framework how can i use PDO

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: yes i did ,  mysql_real_escape_string ,addslash

Comment: if my database contain string like  'Lgf

Comment: and i'm searching for \'Lgf ,how can i search for that if i added a back slash  sorry for my english

Comment: I'm Creating project in kruti dev 010 font  for language  hindi  and kruti dev  
font contains word like 'Dfs>? , d;<"r

Comment: can you try to pass string as a variable ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution to this is to use the native CodeIgniter query builder:
Where ever your are building your insert statements in your application try the following, of course replacing the values of name and description with the appropriate information.:

```
$this->db->insert('tablename',array('name' => 'x"ydv', 'description' => '"\'"dbs"' ));
```