# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry am getting this errors in my errors logs

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in /home/payassur/public_html/admin/index.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 /home/payassur/public_html/admin/index.php(13): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM u...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/payassur/public_html/admin/index.php on line 13
```

below is line 13

```
  $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $u_id");
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Looks like $u_id is empty. please check

Comment: I have checked. u_id is user id

Comment: So `$u_id` has a value? How Looks your query if you echo it out?

Comment: No, $u_id not have value but id.

Comment: But the variable must have a value. if not your SQL can not work

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =` is not a valid SQL

Comment: so what is valid sql? yes the id have value

Comment: What would you achive with that query? valid SQL is for instance `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = <value>` where value is a number, or `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id is null` if you are looking for rows which has no id

Comment: that is SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = user_id

Comment: PHP and SQL are different languages executed by different programs, some times even in different computers. MySQL cannot see your PHP code, all that matters is the SQL code you send.

Comment: @AbiodunVictor You should give us more context arround your Problem. please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You're query is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection), people have figured this out and thus are trying to inject the database. That is why you having those errors in your error log. You should start using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379483/446594) to prevent SQL injections

```
if (isset($u_id) && trim($u_id) != '') {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :u_id');
    $stmt->exectue(array('u_id' => $u_id,));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
}else{
    $results = [];
}
```

Comment: That wan't help, if $_id is blank as in the case of OP

Comment: Why should it be blank? Someone could have changed a querystring to `www.example.com?u_id='`. OP is stating he/she finds this error in the error log, so sure it's not because OP is still testing his/her own code?

Comment: see the comment of op: *No, $u_id not have value*

Comment: Well OP said `$u_id` was holding an id, not a value, `$u_id not have value but id`, thats does not makes it empty