# Insert data from a table to other

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (users) that looks like this:

```
ID |    CODE   | Name
---+----------+---------
 1 |    00A    | Tom
 2 |    12E    | Steve
 3 |    A4B    | Maria
```

Now I have other table to insert data, and I need to insert `user_id`. The thing is I receive only the user code from a document.
I have to search in the users table the id that corresponds to that code.

I imagine I have to do something like this:

```
$code = 123 

$query="select from users where id=$code"

$user_id = $query

$sql = "insert into table values ($user_id)"
```

I know the SQL/PHP code is not complete, I'm just looking for the correct LOGIC to this. Maybe there's a way to search and insert at the same query.

Comment: `insert into table values (select user_id from users where id=$code)`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @bassxzero that (and OP's post) would leave the code vulnerable to SQL injection. Isabella, I would look at a post like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379433/mysql-prepared-statements) to ensure you're not leaving your system vulnerable

Comment: @kchason ...or in this case (since it's just an id), make sure that `$code` is cast as an integer with either `$code = (int) $code;` or `$code = intval($code);`.

Comment: Agreed, but it's still better to encourage best practices except in cases where parameter binding isn't possible (column/table names etc).

Comment: The general format for an INSERT is `INSERT INTO `table` (`column1`) VALUES ($column1);` so you'd want to follow that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have to search in the users table the id that corresponds to that code** from your question do this.

```
$code = 123 

$query="select * from users where code=$code"; //your variable code if confusing me, but it is fetching id based on id but different variable name do this.

$query="select * from users where id=$code";

$runquery = mysqli_query($con, $query); //$con is your database connection parameter 

$fetchuser = mysqli_fetch_array($runquery);

$idofuser = $fetchuser['id'];


$sql = "insert into table values ($idofuser)";
$coolrun = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($coolrun){
 echo "The query ran.";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! It only worked after add * to select from.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with one query, But you have to use PDO or somethign similar to avoid SQL injection

```
Insert Into table
Select user_id from users
WHERE id = $code;
```

Check this out about [How Can I Prevent Sql Injection In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php), you would follow:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`column_name`) VALUES (SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `id`= ?)");
$statement->bind_param("i", $id);
$statement->execute();
```

[PDO](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) would be:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`column_name`) VALUES (SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `id`= :id)");
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
$statement->execute();
```

I included the `column_name` because I assume your table has multiple columns, and you want to specify into which column it should be inserted.