# Why does Emulating a Prepared Statement Fail with Null?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

From the PHP [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php), it states that:

> PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES Enables or disables emulation of prepared
>   statements. Some drivers do not support native prepared statements or
>   have limited support for them. Use this setting to force PDO to either
>   always emulate prepared statements (if TRUE), or to try to use native
>   prepared statements (if FALSE). It will always fall back to emulating
>   the prepared statement if the driver cannot successfully prepare the
>   current query. Requires bool.

I have a query that goes like this:

```
$type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
if($_POST['code'] == "") $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE Product SET code=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['code'], $type);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

I realise that without setting the following statement, I would get a `'0'` instead of a `NULL` value (when `$_POST['code'] == ""`) into my database using the code above. Why is that so?

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

**UPDATE:**

Although disabling of the emulation works for me, I would prefer to use it because like the OP in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535464/when-not-to-use-prepared-statements), basically all my queries are only executed once per script execution. Therefore, having the statements prepared does not gain me any advantage and creates unnecessary calls to the database as shown in the general query log below:

```
Emulation Disabled
22 Connect user@localhost on Database
22 Prepare UPDATE Product SET code=? WHERE id=?
22 Execute UPDATE Product SET code='abc' WHERE id='123'
22 Close stmt   
22 Quit

Emulation Enabled
22 Connect user@localhost on Database
22 Query UPDATE Product SET code='abc' WHERE id='123'
22 Quit
```

Any help to solve the `NULL` issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can say at least that empty string IS NOT equal to NULL

Comment: and also posing logs, irrelevant to the code above, I wouldn't call a reasonable action.

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel. That solves it. I didn't think it is so easy. You should put it down as answer for me to accept. Thanks.

Comment: The log is to show the advantages of having emulation and explain why I need to solve this question :)

Comment: errr... what worked? the value must be NULL to make this binding type work? I merely meant that it may be erroneous approach to save an empty string as a NULL

Comment: The only advantage of the log is to show the actual result of the actual code. Otherwise it makes very little sense. Aren't you curious yourself, what SQL query PDO created out of your code?

Comment: I should add `$_POST['code'] = NULL` at the second line after the if condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try bind `null` for `PDO::PARAM_NULL`.

```
$type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
if($_POST['code'] == "") {
    $_POST['code'] = null;
    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE Product SET code=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['code'], $type);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

In fact, it seems you don't need use `PDO::PARAM_NULL`, the code below will also insert `null`.

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['code'] ? $_POST['code'] : null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: I see.. Your answer comes a bit late, see the discussion above. But it is correct. I wonder if Col. Shrapnel wants to have it. Will accept your answer if he does not post. Thanks...